# Perform Authentication in Spring with different users

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I just started working with Spring and I'm trying to build an application that manages the students, professors, courses .. of a university. I have two type of user in my application : Administrator and Professor. I need them both to be able to perform log in operation, but they should not be displayed the same content. I am a little lost regarding the exact method with which I can identify a professor and an admin. I also did not really understand this InMemoryAuthentication thing and AuthenticationProvider in general. Can someone explain to me how can I fulfill this task ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-and-registration

Comment: thank you but in this tutorial they are using inMemoryAuthentication,which I don't want to use . I want to make an authentication with the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203522/discussion-between-rcvaram-and-jotaro).